# Methods still being called in view after I switch views?

Tags: ios, methods, view

Currently in View A I call a few methods to animating some UIImageView's while the view is open. These methods get called when the animations are finished so pretty much these animations go forever **while the view is still open**. What I do not want though, is any of these methods to get called when I switch views like I do below.

Why do my methods in View A still get called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a strong reference to your view it won't be deallocated.  Removing it from the superview only drops the retain count by one.

Comment: I only have a setter with nonatomic, retain in my app delegate and that is because View A is the main view it goes to. The first view the app sees.

Comment: Also I just checked and even if I do assign only, it still calls the method in View A at the speed of a game loop. I have tried every possible thing in the book to stop that animation method from getting called but I just can't!

Comment: I managed to fix it by using the BOOL that the UIView animation completion handler has, now I know why it is there!